# ASP.NET Manual user authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I am working for the DOD. The application they have requested is web based, and will be on their internal network. The request is for CAC authentication, which is easy enough... The remaining problem is authenticating a user. The CAC authentication is happening at the IIS level, so by the time the user gets to the application, all I am doing (or had planned on doing) is checking the ID on the CAC, and comparing it to a user table in the database. If the user exists (and has been approved), then they are off and running in the system. If they do not exist, then they are pushed to the registration screen.

Given my lack of experience with web development, I am unsure if I need to actually authenticate the user in some way beyond the CAC authentication, or if I can just manually assign roles to the user and let the roles dictate what can or cannot be done in the application. Windows authentication is not an option; while this application is internal for the military, it is accessible from different mil networks.

If I do indeed need to authenticate a user... this is where I run into trouble. I have not found anything that says there is a way to manually authenticate a user. I could use the standard ASP tables in the database, but it seems... messy... to include things that won't be used (meaning the password field would always be an empty string - why include it in the db if it isn't being used?).

Thanks in advance for any help... If there's links to where I can read more about the authentication process, those would be very much appreciated as will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on several DOE projects that use the same idea.  What we normally do for web applications is to enable Windows authentication on the app.  This will allow pass-through of user credentials and keep out anyone without credentials.

I also like to add role based authorization into the mix and then use AD groups to allow/deny users on specific apps.

Comment: My problem is that not everyone accessing the application will be in the active directory of which this application is a part... Unless there's a way to utilize Windows authentication across disparate networks of which I'm not aware. We're all still waiting for the great AD reorg that will put all military networks into one, but until that happens, I can't see a way that windows authentication will work.

Comment: It's not finished yet, but take a look at my QuickFrame project.  The authorization scheme is built such that users from disparate sources can be authorized through the same method.   Roles are defined and assigned to resources.  Users and/or groups can then be added to these roles.  The only thing I have done at this point is Active Directory because that's all I've needed, but I think you an see where I'm going with it.  https://github.com/82dsoldier/QuickFrameMVC/tree/master/QuickFrame.Mvc